# Integrate pagy and meilisearch for pagination and search in to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, meilisearch, pagy

What's the best way to integrate pagy_search in to my index if I'm already using Pagy? In my controller I currently have:

```
def index

    @gold_drivers = Driver.gold_plan
    @silver_drivers = Driver.silver_plan
    @free_drivers = Driver.free_plan

    @pagy, @drivers = pagy_array(
      @gold_drivers + @silver_drivers + @free_drivers,
      page: params[:page],
      items: 16
    )

    if params[:query].present?
      @drivers = @gold_drivers + @silver_drivers + @free_drivers
      drivers_search = Driver.pagy_search(params[:query])
      @pagy, @drivers = pagy_meilisearch(drivers_search, items: 25, page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

I have a Driver model which delegate's to a Profile model. Unfortunately when I click search I get

`Driver#first_name delegated to profile.first_name, but profile is nil: #<Driver id: 224...` as I know this driver does not have a profile, but the query run for @gold_drivers = Driver.gold_plan / @silver_drivers = Driver.silver_plan etc should not select a driver without a profile.

The query behind Driver.gold_plan is:

```
find_by_sql("SELECT drivers.*, (profiles.no_races + profiles.no_poles + profiles.no_podiums + profiles.no_wins) AS scores FROM drivers INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.driver_id = drivers.id INNER JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.driver_id = drivers.id WHERE subscriptions.status = 'active' AND profiles.first_name != null OR profiles.first_name != '' AND subscriptions.stripe_plan = '#{ENV["GOLD_ANNUAL"]}' OR subscriptions.stripe_plan = '#{ENV["GOLD_MONTH"]}' GROUP BY scores, drivers.id ORDER BY scores DESC")
```

In that query I'm using `"AND profiles.first_name != null OR profiles.first_name != ''"` which works in the pagy_page section - but not in the pagy_search section.

Any direction with this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: your code is extremely inefficient because:

1. It does 3 queries instead of 1
2. It pulls all the records into memory (potentially crashing your server) and joins them into an array using yet more memory to create another possibly huge object
3. It uses `pagy_array`, that [should never be used that way](https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/array#warning)

So let's start to change that.

1. Do not use `+` but create a single scope that ORs the 3 scopes (gold, silver, plan) together (that should be AR relations too, not literal queries). That will get you a single AR Relation not loading anything into memory yet
2. Use the AR Relation directly with `pagy` instead of `pagy_array`: that will pull only the page of records that you are going to need, not the whole bunch of records that you don't need
3. Use the same AR Relation for `pagy_meilisearch` and your problem will probably disappear without further changes. If it won't, then look into your scope.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your comment. I'll give it a go.

Comment: So this is what I have so far:     scope :all_drivers, -> {
        Driver.joins(:profile, :subscriptions).where.not(profile: { first_name: [nil, '']     }).where(subscriptions: { status: 'active', stripe_plan: [ ENV["GOLD_ANNUAL"],     ENV["GOLD_MONTHLY"], ENV["SILVER_ANNUAL"],     ENV["SILVER_MONTHLY"]]})and(includes(:subscriptions).where(subscriptions:     { id: nil }))
      }
I've got a little way to go yet, but I'm having issues when the profile equals null. - Driver#first_name delegated to profile.first_name, but profile is nil